# Javascript not working in Webview

Tags: javascript, java, webview

I have a simple javascript where I want to give value to these input which is username and password. I open the website by using webview. When the webview fully loaded, the username and password place doesn't change at all.

The website : http://www.malaysiakini.com/login/en/form

My source code for the javascript :

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            view.loadUrl("javascript: {" +
            "$('input#username').val(" + user + ");\n" +
            "$('input#username').val(\"password\");\n" +
            "document.querySelectorAll(\"button[type='submit']\")[0].click();}");

        }
```

Comment: your "javascript uri" is invalid javascript (missing a closing `}` for a start, and you really want a javascript uri to result in `undefined` or it wont work like you want

Comment: That was an embarrassing mistake. I didn't realise that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        view.loadUrl("javascript: {" +
        "$('input#username').val('" + user + "');\n" +
        "$('input#username').val(\"password\");\n" +
        "document.querySelectorAll(\"button[type='submit']\")[0].click();}");

    }
```

Silly me, I missed the single quotes